# .htaccess pretty url's for legacy files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've taken over a project which has references to "lorem.php" not making use of Mod Rewrite unfortunately, I'm finding it an eye sore and would love to knock the extension off (at least).

The ideal URL would look like "/process-app" would map to "/processApp.php"

My issue is the camelCase naming convention used throughout everything.

- I can't rename the files due to legacy URL's being referenced
- Doing individual file references for every file is out of the question due to the amount of files that exist, a dynamic solution is required

I doubt there is a way to capitalize the first letter of the variable within the rule?

Here is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-([A-z]+)?$ $1$2.php
```

But the URL to make the correct file reference needs to be "/process-App"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I doubt there is a way to capitalize the first letter of the variable
>   within the rule?

Don't doubt, it is possible.

In *httpd.conf* add this into vhost block domain:

```
RewriteMap upper int:toupper
```

Then, in your htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-([a-z])([a-z]+)$ $1${upper:$2}$3.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-([A-Z][a-z]+)$ $1$2.php [L]
```

Comment: Appreciate the response but unfortunately hitting "/process-app" would map to "processapp.php", but the actual file is lower camel case "processApp.php".

Comment: Do you have access to httpd.conf ? Otherwise, i will try to manage a solution

Comment: You sir are a legend! Would there be any significant performance issues with this method?

Comment: It seems like there's no performance issue. It declares the map in server/virtualhost context. Once created, you can call it in the context of RewriteCond/RewriteRule which is, in your case, only when rule is matching. And it is by far faster than a "manual" method